# No module named copy_reg in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, git-submodules, python-2.x

I have a git submodule that has this line

```
import copy_reg
```

It works for Python 2.
However, there is no module named **copy_reg** in Python3.
The Python3 module name is **copyreg**.

I cannot change code in the git submodule since it will break in future updates.
How to make the code work for both Python2 and Python3 without modifying module's code.

Answer (score 3):

```
try:
    import copy_reg
except:
    import copyreg as copy_reg
```

Comment: The solution is correct but this code is in a different package and I am not allowed to edit that package (Even if I edit now, future updates of that package will break the workflow anyway). Is there any other way I can safely import without any exceptions?

Comment: You'll get exception if you try to import in different version but you'll have to handle it. You can check exception and if it's due to import of this module then you can do this which might work. Read module where import is kept as string in memory and then replace import copy_reg with import copyreg as copy_reg and then try to compile that string which has python content as python module. I am not sure whether this will work as i have never tried. I am just guessing one approach.